# Custom URL Scheme IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, url-scheme, info.plist

I have an application which will be launched from other apps which are mine too. But my purpose is to launch my app and do nothing with the URL. Its just a way of enabling the user to switch between apps without any data exchange.

Do I need to implement `handleOpenURL` or similar methods to handle the URL to filter out unwanted commands like apple mentions in [Secure Coding guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/ValidatingInput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007246-SW3), or just specifying the scheme in the info.plist (along with URL identifier and document role as Viewer) is enough secure considering the fact that I am not doing anything with the URL?

Comment: If your app does nothing, there is nothing to hack. But I suggest you to implement `openURL:` for further extension and for code transparency.

Comment: @kelin Thanks for your comment. So, are you suggesting that I implement `openURL:` and then inside the method do nothing?

Comment: Just return NO, it will be ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement `application:handleOpenURL:` or 
`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`, and return YES. The second method is preferred according to Apple's docs.

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
  return YES;
}
```

You could additionally check the scheme, source application, or other conditions, and return YES or NO accordingly. If you have several of your apps communicating you can check for the source application or pass data using the annotation.

```
NSString* myappScheme = @"anindya";  // or even better read it from your plist
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
  return [url.scheme isEqualToString: myappScheme];
}
```

As far as security is concerned, you don't really do anything else with the URL, so there's no problem. Apple's advice in this regard means if you get a URL from another app, you have to carefully parse it and assume it might be malicious. If you also check the source application you can be sure to only get data from your own apps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer. One question: if the scheme is wrong then I thought the application will not launch on the first place. So if my scheme is anindya and some app tries to launch as anindya123, my app will not get launched. Then why we are doing the check, would you please explain?

Comment: When we return NO here, the URL does not get executed. i.e. this method "asks the delegate to open a resource identified by URL." So, "If you don't return YES your app will not open" -- does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Checking the URL scheme is not necessary, you are correct. The OS will only call apps that document support for URL schemes in their `info.plist`. You can just as well return `YES` without doing any kind of check.

Comment: Thanks @orkoden. If you update the answer, I can mark it as the "answer". Because, `return [url.scheme isEqualToString: myappScheme];` seems to be pointless, and as you stated later, we can just return YES (or NO for that matter) here since nothing is being done here with the URL.